# Home Network Interference on Cat6 Unshielded cable

Tags: home-automation, noise-reduction, ethernet

**Background:**
I live in a level two apartment and want to get WiFi in my individual lockup basement garage and install a security camera.
I have pulled a Cat6 UTP cable to the garage via the services shaft being careful to avoid some of the mains cables. At a few sections in the shaft they cross over one another and are very close together. For the majority of the run (100 feet in total) in the shaft they are about 12 inches apart with other building network cables except for the situations already mentioned where they are close to one another.
**Problem:**
I cant seem to get any network connection in the garage to the router in my apartment using the new Cat 6 cable and I suspect interference from the AC mains cables.
I have tested each of the four pairs to ensure integrity of the cable by terminating each pair end and got a complete circuit to ensure I did not accidentally break / cut the cable during pull through.
**Question:**
Assuming that the interference is from the Mains cables (or other devices in the ceiling void I can't see) is it likely that the interference would be reduced or eliminated if I were to replace the Cat6 UTP with Cat6 Shielded cable ?

Comment: Just to eliminate the obvious - are you certain that you wired each end of the cable correctly? Did you just crimp a RJ45 plug to each end or a socket in a panel/plate?

Comment: Agreed, the "mains interference" issue seems pretty unlikely.  I would positively exhaust every other possibility before worrying about that.

Comment: Just to clearify @brhans comment: Cat6 cable (and similar) has 4 twisted pairs. The pairs can be interchanged (so long as both ends are consistent) but the two wires in the pair must be wired correctly relative to each other. For example, one pair is blue and blue/white. The center two terminals of the RJ45 are for one pair. If you put blue on one and orange (instead of blue/white) on the other, it won't work. You should look up T-568 and just use it (either A or B but be consistent).

Comment: Thank you for the prompt feedback. I terminated each end using 568B coding standard and took care when doing the punch down. I then used a commercial patch cable to connect to each device (router and Apple Express) from my 568 coded wall jack at both ends. However I will have a close look at each end again.

Comment: I have now tested my apartment end jack termination which connects to my router (located in another room of my apartment) by using it to my AppleExpress and all works fine. In other words, the jack push down termination I did in the apartment is working fine. This means the problem is : 1. my push down termination in the garage, 2. integrity of the cat6 cable or 3. interference.

Comment: I have since found my problem - it was a bad termination (push down) on the RJ45 jack in the garage (my fault). Thank you for your help in suggesting this as it stopped me from following the more expensive STP route.